# Excel formula Index & Compare

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns, in col A, I have the name of the borrower and in col B I have the dates. The borrowers are not sorted in alphabetical order. I need a help in writing a formula which will search for the specific borrower in Col. A and if the same borrower is listed multiple times and if there is a date entered in the corresponding Col B for that borrower, then it in Col. C it should show that date is already entered.

```
Borrower    Date    Desired Result
-------------------------------------
B1      10/15/2018  Date Entered
B1                  Date Entered
B1                  Date Entered
B2      5/5/2020    Date Entered
B2      5/5/2020    Date Entered
B2                  Date Entered
B1                  Date Entered
B3                  NO Date ENTERED
B2                  Date Entered
B3                  NO Date ENTERED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS() in an IF():

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"),"Date Entered","NO Date ENTERED")
```

[image]

Comment: @Nomi please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: just did :) Thanks again